# Rebuild sphinx index fail

Tags: sphinx

We have 4 [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) indexes built using data from one table. All indexes have the same source settings except that they take different documents. We have checks like this `mod(id, 4) = <index number>` to distribute documents and document attributes between indexes.

Question: **One of the four indexes (the same one) fails to rebuild almost every time we rebuild the indexes.** Other indexes never have this issue and are rebuild correctly.

We have partitioned the documents and attribute tables. For example this is how documents table is partitioned:

```
PARTITION BY HASH(mod(id, 4))(
  PARTITION `p0` COMMENT '',
  PARTITION `p1` COMMENT '',
  PARTITION `p2` COMMENT '',
  PARTITION `p3` COMMENT ''
);
```

We think that indexer hangs after it has received all documents but before it starts receiving attributes. We can see this when we check sessions on MySQL server.

The index which fails to rebuild is using `mod(id, 4) = 0` condition.

We use Sphinx 2.0.4-release on Ubuntu 64bit 12.04.02 LTS.

---

Data source config

```
source ble_job_2 : ble_job
{
    sql_query = select job_notice.id as id, \
        body, title, source, company, \
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(insertDate) as date, \
        substring(company, 1, 1) as companyletter, \
        job_notice.locationCountry as country, \
        location_us_state.stateName as state, \
        0 as expired, \
        clusterId, \
        groupCity, \
        groupCityAttr, \
        job_notice.cityLat as citylat, \
        job_notice.cityLng as citylng, \
        job_notice.zipLat as ziplat, \
        job_notice.zipLng as ziplng, \
        feedId, job_notice.rating as rating, \
        job_notice.cityId as cityid \
        from job_notice \
        left join location_us_state on job_notice.locationState = location_us_state.stateCode \
        where job_notice.status != 'expired' \
        and mod(job_notice.id, 4) = 1

    sql_attr_multi = uint attr from query; \
        select noticeId, attributeId as attr from job_notice_attribute where mod(noticeId, 4) = 1
} # source ble_job_2
```

Index config

```
index ble_job_2
{
    type            = plain
    source          = ble_job_2
    path            = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/ble_job_2

    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology      = none
    stopwords       = /etc/sphinxsearch/stopwords/blockwords.txt
    min_word_len    = 1
    charset_type    = utf-8
    enable_star     = 0
    html_strip      = 0
} # index_ble_job_2
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Warm regards.

Comment: How do you define your sql_query for these indexes? I thought with the partition engine, you can't directly access the underlying tables, only the combined table.

Comment: I put our configs here. I can not access the underlying table directly but I think that when I have this check `mod(id, 4) = 0` it access the underlying partition. I think this because I can see the performance improvements when have added partiotions.

Comment: @barryhunter thank you for your help. Your other answer for the question on 'Bad query in Sphinx MVA' helped us a lot because we first tried to apply range to sql_attr_multi query too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily we have fixed the issue.

We have applied the [range query](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.4/sql.html#ranged-queries) setup and this helped us to get index rebuild stable. I think this is because Sphinx runs several queries and each returns limited relatively small set of results. This allows MySQL to complete the query normally and sent all the results back to Sphinx.

The same issue is described on Sphinx forum [Indexer Hangs & MySQL Query Sleeps](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=3961).

---

The changes in the config for data source are

```
    sql_query_range = SELECT MIN(id),MAX(id) FROM job_notice where mod(job_notice.id, 4) = 1
    sql_range_step = 200000
    sql_query = select job_notice.id as id, \
    ...
        and mod(job_notice.id, 4) = 1 and job_notice.id >= $start AND job_notice.id <= $end
```

---

Please note that no ranges should be applied to sql_attr_multi query - [Bad query in Sphinx MVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235608/bad-query-in-sphinx-mva)

Comment: Thats not quite true, using ranges on your MVA queries is perfectly valid and possible. That question you linked to was not used ranges. That user thought the sql_attr_multi was run once for every document, its not, its run (as a single query or multiple with ranges) to get all documents in the index.